# How to find different percent of an amount?

Tags: percentages

This is a simple calculation but i couldn't figure out how to calculate it. I know how to find percent of a number, for example, 80% of 1600 is 1280. However, let us take an example of $1600 and I want to divide it into different values of percentages, for example, divide %1600 into 3 of 100%, 1 of 80% and 2 of 70%(meaning divide 1600 into 100%, 100%,100%,80%,70%,70%).
Any thoughts would be helpful. Thank You.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am a bit unclear of what you mean by "divide $1600 into different values of percentages." Can you elaborate?

Comment: @KingLogic: lets say $1600 is a tip of a day in a restaurant and servers need to divide it into different percentages like  I said above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to divide your $1600$ into six unequal parts that are proportional to $100, 100, 100, 80, 70, 70$. If so, then writing those fractions as percentages makes no sense. In fact, in this case they might as well be $10, 10, 10, 8, 7,7$.

To make the calculation, first compute the sum
$$
10+ 10+ 10+ 8+ 7+ 7 = 52.
$$

Then the first  part will be
$$
\frac{10}{52} \times 1600
$$
and so on, up to
$$
\frac{7}{52} \times 1600.
$$

Comment: I understand how to do it in fractions. But I want to distribute $1600 for 6 persons in that 3 persons will get 100% and 1 person will get 80% and 2 persons 70%. Does this make sense?

Comment: No it does not. If the first person gets $100\%$ then that person gets it all and there is nothing left for anyone else. Perhaps $1600$ is a base amount and you want to give the people $1600, 1600, 1600, 0.8\times 1600, 0.7 \times 1600, 0.7 \times 1600$. But your comment says this isn't what you mean. To divide the $1600$ into six parts, use the fraction method in this answer.

Comment: Exactly, fraction is the only choice